# CSS Grid with SVG Background

Tags: html, css, svg, css-grid

I am using CSS Grid, which works great, but want to have a background SVG that the grid sits on top of.

For example, here is the HTML:

```
<div className="wrapper">
    <div className="item">
        <div id="wave">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 500 200" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M0.00,92.27 C216.83,192.92 304.30,8.39 500.00,109.03 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z"></path></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="item">1</div>
    <div className="item">2</div>
    <div className="item">3</div>
</div>
```

...and the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-columns: 100vw;
    gap: 10px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
}

.item {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

...which obviously only places the SVG in the top row. How can I sit the SVG behind the grid? I also tried wrapping the wrapper with a div and seeing the position to absolute.

Should look like this (svg wave in blue, grid items in pink):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the wrapper approach:

1. Create a wrapper element with `position: relative`.
2. Add the `svg` element with `position: absolute` and `top: 0`, `right: 0`, etc...
3. Add the grid element with `position: relative`.

The wrapper having `position: relative` allows the `svg` to size itself using the wrapper as its parent. The `position: relative` on the grid creates a new stacking context above the `svg` which also has its own stacking context thanks to `position: absolute`.

Here's a demo:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  fill: lightblue;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  gap: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0.00,92.27 C216.83,192.92 304.30,8.39 500.00,109.03 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: Or set the svg in the css background

Answer (score 1):

A lot less HTML and CSS when you place your SVG in the `.grid background`

Convert your SVG to CSS in: https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

Only drawback: You can't style the SVG with CSS, you have to `fill` the SVG path with an attribute.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,50px);
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  gap: 10px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 500 200'%3E%3Cpath fill='lightblue' d='M0 92C217 193 304 8 500 109L500 0 0 0Z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: cover;
}

.item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m worried that if I convert the SVG to an image it will take too long to load, especially since it covers the whole background of a screen-wide div. SVG loads instantly.

Comment: It is **not** a binary image. The SVG is still SVG. And parsed by the same code deep down in the Browser engine before being injected(or updated) in the DOM. It __*could be*__ faster (never tested it) because CSS is not applied to the background-image SVG version.. so the Browser engine has **less work** to do on reflows and repaints.

Comment: interesting, thank you.

Comment: I used a wrapper because that was the direction the question was already heading. If it were a personal project, I would likely take this approach instead. +1